# print_req_error: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0

Tags: disk, sector, sata, dmesg

I have samsung disk after a while the device is found on /dev/sdb but not the partitions. The smartools is not able to make a test of the unit and the dmesg traces show the follow information about is not able to access sector 0. For me the problem is clear the disk is broken in some hardware part and the PCB board is not able to communicate with the disk. I would like have some other point of view about the problem, keeping in mind is a hardware problem.

```
[11087.417346] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[11087.417354] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[11087.417422] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[11087.417426] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[11087.417429] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[11087.417439] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[11087.417518] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[11087.417569] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[11087.417647]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[11087.737073] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[11087.737078] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[11087.977053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[11087.977057] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[11088.073054] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[11088.073057] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[11088.285077] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[12440.024126] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[12440.217672] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61b6
[12440.217678] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12440.217680] usb 2-3: Product: Samsung M3 Portable
[12440.217683] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Samsung M3 Portable
[12440.217685] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: BFB47DFB1D000023
[12440.219046] scsi host4: uas
[12440.230061] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  M3 Portable      1306 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[12440.230907] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[12452.230564] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[12455.236046] .
[12462.276102] .
[12468.900015] .
[12475.940060] .
[12482.980062] .
[12490.019988] .
[12492.293889] not responding...
[12492.294535] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 281474976710656 512-byte logical blocks: (144 PB/128 PiB)
[12492.294537] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[12492.294687] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[12492.294688] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[12492.295029] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[12492.295257] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[12492.295684] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[12492.295687] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[12492.295689] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
```

Do you have some idea what is going on? Can I recover the disk?